# Locate video relationships in OpenXML

Tags: video, openxml

So I'm writing a pptx parser and using OpenXML to get the data loaded in. It's all going pretty well (that's a lie - I'm actually ready to throw the computer across the room and jump out of the window), but I've run into an issue with loading videos that I simply can't figure out. The problem is that OpenXML doesn't seem to be able to locate the relationship tag that specifies video URIs.

What I've done is written code to cycle through the parts in the slide and log out their Ids, like so:

```
SlidePart slidePart = ...;
foreach(var curPart in slidePart.Parts)
  Console.WriteLine("Part ID: " + curPart.RelationshipId);
```

So that works great - it logs out all of the relationships specified in the slide.xml.rels file - except for the video relationships for the relevant file. I can see the video relationship in the rels file, and it matches the link ID of the videoFile tag in the slide, but I can't figure out how to get at it through code. I've got image loading working fine (OpenXML can find the image relationships). Are video relationships treated differently than other relationships? How can I get at the video URIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Video releationships are stored in the ExternalReleationships collection of a SlidePart.

Powerpoint embeds a video (external file) into a presentation in the following way (simplified):

1. It creates a p:video (class `Video`) tag within a p:timing (class `Timing`) tag for
    the slide containing the video.
2. The p:video tag contains a child called p:cMediaNode (class `CommonMediaNode`).
3. The p:cMediaNode contains a child called p:tgtEl (class `TargetElement`).
4. Again, the p:cMediaNode contains a child called p:spTgt (class `ShapeTarget`) which
   points to the ID of the picture shape releated to the video. The ID of the picture
   shape is stored in the `NonVisualDrawingProperties` `Id` member. 
   So, the video is   connected to the picture shape via these Ids.
5. Furthermore, the picture shape contains a child called a:videoFile (class `VideoFromFile`).
   The class VideoFromFile has a member called `Link` which points to the Id of 
   the external releationship.

I highy recommend you to download the *OpenXML SDK 2.0 productivity tool*. This tool
allows you to inspect the generated XML of your presentation file.

The following code enumerates all videos for all slides in a given presentation.
For each video the Uri to the external file is printed. This is done by finding
the releated external releationship for the given video.

```
using (var doc = PresentationDocument.Open("c:\\temp\\presentation.pptx", false))
{
  var presentation = doc.PresentationPart.Presentation;

  foreach (SlideId slideId in presentation.SlideIdList)
  {
    SlidePart slidePart = doc.PresentationPart.GetPartById(slideId.RelationshipId) as SlidePart;
    if (slidePart == null || slidePart.Slide == null)
    {
      continue;
    }

    Slide slide = slidePart.Slide;

    var videos = slide.Descendants<Video>();

    Console.Out.WriteLine("Found videos for slide ID: {0}", slideId.Id);
    foreach (Video video in videos)
    {
      ShapeTarget shapeTarget = video.Descendants<ShapeTarget>().FirstOrDefault();

      Console.Out.WriteLine("ShapeTargetId = {0}", shapeTarget.ShapeId);

      var videoFromFile = slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Descendants<Picture>().
                Where<Picture>(p => p.NonVisualPictureProperties.Descendants<NonVisualDrawingProperties>().FirstOrDefault().Id == shapeTarget.ShapeId).
                FirstOrDefault().Descendants<VideoFromFile>().FirstOrDefault();                

      Console.Out.WriteLine("Releationship ID: {0}", videoFromFile.Link);

      var externalReleationship = 
                slidePart.ExternalRelationships.Where(er => er.Id == videoFromFile.Link).FirstOrDefault();

      if(externalReleationship == null) // Then it must be embedded
      {
         ReferenceRelationship rr = slidePart.GetReferenceRelationship(videoFromFile.Link);
         if (rr != null)
         {
           Console.Out.WriteLine(rr.Uri.OriginalString);
         }
      }
      else
      {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Path to video file: {0}", externalReleationship.Uri.AbsolutePath);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you could also directly enumerate the a:videoFile (class `VideoFromFile`) tags.
See the code below.

```
foreach (SlideId slideId in presentation.SlideIdList)
{
  SlidePart slidePart = doc.PresentationPart.GetPartById(slideId.RelationshipId) as SlidePart;
  if (slidePart == null || slidePart.Slide == null)
  {
    continue;
  }

  Slide slide = slidePart.Slide;

  var videos = slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Descendants<VideoFromFile>();

  foreach (VideoFromFile video in videos)
  {                                
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Releationship ID: {0}", video.Link);

    var externalReleationship =
           slidePart.ExternalRelationships.Where(er => er.Id == video.Link).FirstOrDefault();

    if(externalReleationship == null) 
    {
        ReferenceRelationship rr = slidePart.GetReferenceRelationship(videoFromFile.Link);
        if (rr != null)
        {
          Console.Out.WriteLine(rr.Uri.OriginalString);
        }
    }
    else
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("Path to video file: {0}", externalReleationship.Uri.AbsolutePath);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately my problem is elsewhere - I've already got the id of the video from the a:videoFile tag in the p:pic element. The issue is that OpenXML isn't acknowledging the existence of that ID - even if I just enumerate the external relationships of the slide and log them all out, the relationship with the id of the video isn't there. Which is odd, since if I view the XML in notepad, the ID is there, along with the proper URI. Any ideas?

Comment: @LincolnGreen: Could you upload your file? So I will have a look at it. By the same token could you post your code reading the id of the video and the external releationships?

Comment: Also, if it's of any interest, I went ahead and ran the sample code, which threw a Null Exception on the line where you log the Uri of the external relationship.

Comment: @LincolnGreen: A null reference exception at this point means that the external releationship was not found. If you upload a sample powerpoint presentation then I will have a look at it.

Comment: @LincolnGreen: This is a MS Office2010 file. The video is embedded into the presentation. You can get the URI by using the following code: `ReferenceRelationship rr = slidePart.GetReferenceRelationship(videoFromFile.Link);                    
Console.Out.WriteLine(rr.Uri.OriginalString);` I am still researching how to determine wether or not the video is embedded. I will come back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me resurrecting this long-dead question, but I've just run into exactly the same problem and I have a solution that doesn't require digging in the slide XML to find the  elements. It turns out video and media parts don't appear in the `slidePart.Parts` collection (as the OP noted) but they *do* appear in another collection `slidePart.DataPartReferenceRelationships`. So I was able to find references to embedded video as follows:

```
SlidePart slidePart = ...;
foreach(var videoPart in slidePart.DataPartReferenceRelationships.OfType<VideoReferenceRelationship>())
  Console.WriteLine("Video Part ID: " + videoPart.Id);
```

Probably a bit late for that to be useful to the OP but hopefully it'll save someone a bit of time :)